# Xamarin Forms Image in NavigationBar not visible

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I have a problem. I created a TabbedPage like this:

```
TabbedBuilder = new TabbedPage
{
    BarBackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#212121"),
    BarTextColor = Color.White
};
TabbedBuilder.Children.Add(new ImageBuilder());
TabbedBuilder.Children.Add(new ImageTemplates());
```

And I set the TabbedPage like this:

```
Navigation.PushAsync(TabbedBuilder);
```

But now I want to add an image in the center of the navigation bar, so in the ImageBuilder page I added the following code:

```
<NavigationPage.TitleView>
    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Image Source="Title_Dark.png" HeightRequest="25" />
    </StackLayout>
</NavigationPage.TitleView>
```

But when I go to that page, no image is in the navigation bar....

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you had set the `TitleView` of the ContentPage `ImageBuilder` . You should init it as `NavigationPage` when add it to the Tabbed Page

```
TabbedBuilder.Children.Add(new NavigationPage(new ImageBuilder()));
TabbedBuilder.Children.Add(new NavigationPage(new ImageTemplates()));
```

But in this way , you app will have two `Navigation Bar` because you had set the MainPage as NavigationPage .

So I suggest that you could change the MainPage instead of call the method `PushAsync`

```
App.Current.MainPage = TabbedBuilder;
```

Normally , we always set the page like **TabbedPage** and **Mater-Detail-Page** as MainPage of App instead of a sub-page.

#### Update

If you do want to navigate between them you could call the method `PushModalAsync`

```
Navigation.PushModalAsync(TabbedBuilder);
```

And pop it when you want to return

```
Navigation.PopAsync();
```

Comment: Okay, but I need to call the TabbedBuilder like the way I do, because I created a TransitionPage, so I get transitions between pages. Is there another way maybe?

Comment: Okay thanks, but still 1 problem.... Using your code removed the names of the pages in the TabbedPage Bar?

Comment: What's the means of  removed the names? Just call `TabbedBuilder.Children.Add(new NavigationPage(new ImageBuilder()));` instead of  `TabbedBuilder.Children.Add(new ImageBuilder());`

Comment: I mean that, when I am on the page of the TabbedBuilder, I have a TabBar with the tab names of the pages that are in the TabbedPage. But all the names are gone, only the tab buttons are shown!

Comment: TabbedBuilder.Children.Add(new NavigationPage(new ImageBuilder()) {Title="xxx" });

Comment: That worked.... Weird, because I have added a Title in the xaml of the 2 pages